# CSS for inplace editing

Tags: html, css

How do I create a label that is editable? I am displaying data in a table, and would like to provide in place editing for the displayed data. What CSS styles can I use for it?

Answer (score 1):

Put a text input box there and make its background same as the background of its container and put 0 border on it and use same font style and color as other items in the table

Answer (score 1):

> What CSS styles can I use for it ?

It's not really a matter of CSS (unless your questions pertains solely to achieving a particular style).

You can:

1. Make all table cells contain inputs. This has the (potentially significant) downside that all data will be submitted to the server if the form is POSTed. I wouldn't recommend this approach unless the table is small or you are never fully submitting the whole page.
2. Change the label to an input on click. When the form is submitted, this value will now be a part of the request.
3. Change the label to an input in response to an action elsewhere (e.g. focusing the row, clicking an edit button next to the row, etc.)
4. Set [contenteditable="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) on the element. This allows rich formatting but also requires that you keep track of the changes the user has made; they will not be submitted to the server unless they are placed into a form field.

You will likely want/need a snippet of JavaScript to change the label to an input (#2 and #3). You will need JavaScript to get the data to the server with approach #4.